# How do I get my code to fit all screen resolutions? Coding from a Macbook and just switched to Windows computer and its all over the place

Tags: jquery, html, css

```js
$(function(){
  $("#Welcome").typed({
    strings: ["PROGRAMMERS / NETWORKERS"],
    typeSpeed: 60
  });
});
```

```css
html {
    background-color: mintcream;
    background-size: 100%;
}




/* Home */



.homeheader button {
    background-color: #4CAF450;
    top: 108px;
    color: white;
    left: -65px;
    padding: 16px;
    font-size: 16px;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    outline: none;
}


.homeheader:hover .homebutton {
    background-color: #3e8e41;
}


.homebutton {
    position: absolute;
    top: 109px;
    right: 835px;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: 470px;

}



/* Ticket */

.dropbtn {
    background-color: #4CAF450;
    color: white;
    padding: 16px;
    font-size: 16px;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    outline: none;
    border-left: solid darkgray;
}

.dropdownticket {
    position: relative;
    top: 100px;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: 475px;
    margin-bottom: 250px;

}


.dropdown-content {
    text-align: center;
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    right: -1px;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    min-width: 118px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    z-index: 1;
}


.dropdown-content a{
    text-align: center;
    color: black;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
}

.dropdownticket:hover .dropdown-content{
    display: block;

}

.dropdownticket:hover .dropbtn {
    background-color: #3e8e41;
}

.dropbtn1 {
    position: relative;
    background-color: #4CAF450;
    color: white;
    outline: none;
    padding: 16px;
    font-size: 16px;
    border: none;
    right: 33px;
    border-left: solid darkgray;

}

/* Testing */



dropbtn1 {
    background-color: #4CAF450;
    color: white;
    padding: -60px;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: 16px;
    border-left: solid blue;
}

.dropdowntest {
    position: relative;
    top: 100px;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: 25px;
    margin-bottom: 250px;

}


.dropdown-content1 {
    text-align: center;
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    bottom: -83px;
    min-width: 99px;
    left: -26px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    z-index: 1;
}


.dropdown-content1 a{
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: -20px;
    color: black;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
}

.dropdown-content1 a:hover {
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
}

.dropdowntest:hover .dropdown-content1{
    display: block;

}

.dropdowntest:hover .dropbtn1 {
    background-color: #3e8e41;
}


/* Get in touch button */

#button button {
    position: absolute;
    left: 578px;
    bottom: 80px;
    font-family: Arial, "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 15px;
    background-color: black;
    border: none;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-decoration: none;

}


a:hover, a:visited, a:link, a:active {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
    color: mediumblue;

}


/* Header */


#nicc {
    color: black;
    position: relative;
    left: 125px;
    width: 1000px;
    height: 200px;
    font-size: 30px;
    bottom: 150px;
    text-align: center;
}


#main1 h1 {
    font-family: Arial, "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, sans-serif;
    color: black;
    position: relative;
    bottom: 140px;
    right: 5px;
    font-size: 15px;
    text-align: center;
}


/* About */



.aboutheader button {
    background-color: #4CAF450;
    color: white;
    top: 108px;
    left: 235px;
    padding: 16px;
    font-size: 16px;
    border: none;
    border-left: solid darkgray;
    cursor: pointer;
    outline: none;
}



.aboutheader:hover .aboutbutton {
    background-color: #3e8e41;
}


.aboutbutton {
    position: absolute;
    top: 109px;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: 470px;

}


/* Nicc logo */



#nicclogo {
    position: relative;
    bottom: 300px;
    left: 470px;

}

#movenavigationcenter {

    display: block;
    align-content:  center;
```

```html
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="home.css">
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/typed.js/1.1.4/typed.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.0-beta.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<body>


<div id="movenavigationcenter">
<div class="homeheader">
    <button class="homebutton">HOME</a></button>
</div>


<div class="dropdownticket">
    <button class="dropbtn">TICKETING</button>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
        <a href="form.html">FORM</a>
        <a href="database.html">DATABASE</a>
        <a href="ticketabout.html">ABOUT</a>
    </div>
</div>


<div class="dropdowntest"> 
    <button class="dropbtn1">TESTING</button>
         <div class="dropdown-content1">
              <a href="logs.html">LOGS</a>
              <a href="testabout.html">ABOUT</a>
    </div>
         </div>   

<div class="aboutheader"> 
    <button class="aboutbutton">ABOUT</button>
</div>
</div>


<!-- WELCOME TO NICC CPS -->

<div id="nicclogo">
    <img src="images/nicc.png" height="60" width="250"/>
</div>


<div id="nicc">
    <h1>WELCOME TO CPS NICC</h1>
</div>

<div id="main1">
    <h1 id="Welcome">PROGRAMMERS / NETWORKERS</h1>
</div>

<div id="button">
    <button><a href="about.html">GET IN TOUCH</a></button>
</div>



<!-- Mouse Hover Button -->

    <script>
         $(function(){
            $("#Welcome").typed({
            strings: ["PROGRAMMERS / NETWORKERS"],
            typeSpeed: 60
            });
         });
    </script>




<!-- ABOUT US -->


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: *all over the place* meaning formatting? that depends in your editor and any plugins or settings you may use..maybe screenshot will show what you mean?

Comment: yes, the format is all over the place. It is fine on my macbook but when I switch over to my PC the text and nav menu isn't in the same spot.

Comment: I linked most of your scripts to their `cdn` counterparts but you still need to provide absolute links to `home.css` and `nicc.png`. Until you don't create a [mcve] nobody can really help. Also please note currently your `CSS` seems incomplete and is invalid.

Comment: Can I post the absolute links here?

Comment: They're the only ones that work here, Green.

Comment: What do you mean by absolute link?

Comment: Exactly what Google and Wikipedia mean by them.

Answer (score 0):

i think the position:absolute did that, you can fix the problem with change width of the part move out your screen with inspect.

Comment: So get rid of position: absolute; ?
And how do I make it fit every screen resolution?

Comment: with the width you should put it with %. example if my screen is 1440px and i want the picture is a half of screen i will put width:50%.